# Printing the field before initialising it seems to print it after I initialise it

Tags: java, allocation

Could you please explain me this strange behaviour?

```
public class Car {

    private int wheels;

    public Car(int wheels) {
        System.out.println("Before: " + wheels);  // prints 3 before initialisation
        this.wheels = wheels;
        System.out.println("After: " + wheels);  // prints 3

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car car = new Car(3);
    }
}
```

If you run this code, you it will print twice `3`, instead of `0`, and just then, after initialisation of the field `wheels`, `3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you refer to `wheels` without the `this` keyword, you refer to the parameter which value is obviously 3.

Change your line to

```
System.out.println("Before: " + this.wheels);
```

or change the parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing the local variable instead of class variable.

Use `this.wheels` to get the class variable before initialization (which will be 0 not 1) and wheels for the local variable which is 3.

Answer (score 0):

The name `wheels` references local variable, not the field `wheels`. In both cases, local variable holds value `3`.

If you want reference object's field, use `this.wheels`.

Answer (score 0):

The code doesn't print the variable you think it prints.

```
public class Car {

private int wheels;//<-- what you think it prints

public Car(int wheels) {//<-- what it actually prints
    System.out.println("Before: " + wheels);  // prints 3 before initialisation
    this.wheels = wheels;
    System.out.println("After: " + wheels);  // prints 3

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car car = new Car(3);
}
}
```

If you want to print the variable, use `this.wheels` instead.